# is it possible in python2.7 to read configuration using ConfigParser from string and not a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm doing some unit testing I'm coming from java world this is very basic for enabling unit tests.

I tried this as suggested in comments using `StringIO` however getting an error what am i doing wrong?

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> output = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> output.write('[general]\n')
>>> output.write('key=value\n')
>>> import ConfigParser
>>> config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read(output)
>>> config.items('general')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 642, in items
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'general'
```

thanks

Comment: Use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html), which is a general API for using strings as file-like objects...

Comment: @l4mpi thanks, I edited the question and added a trial of mine to use `StringIO` what did i do wrong? thanks again.

Comment: @l4mpi got it needed to use `readfp` instead of `read` and also the double write does not work. thanks